# How to Add Custom Options programmatically

Tags: magento-1, custom-options, products, curl, custom-product-type

Products are inserting, but the custom options are not inserting.

```
$mageFilename = '../app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
Mage::app();
umask(0);

$offerJsonURL    =  'http://affilnow.com/component/controller.php';
$Products        =  'get_product_list_by_category_id_and_or_vendor_id';
$Categories      =  'get_parent_categories';
$Latest          =  'get_latest_products';

$fk_= new vendor_data($affiliateID, $token);
$fk_Categories= new category($affiliateID, $token);
$fk_Latest = new latest($affiliateID,$token);

$stores= vendor_data::getVendor($offerJsonURL, 'json');
$categories= category::getCat($offerJsonURL, 'json');
$latest = latest::getLatest($offerJsonURL, 'json');

$product_id='product_id';
$name='name';
$description='description';
$short_d='short_description';
$quantity='quantity';
$weight = 'weight';
$rate ='price';
$sku='sku';
$tax='tax_class_id';
$visibility= 4;
$status='status';
$meta_title='meta_title';
$meta_description='meta_description';
$meta_keyword='meta_keyword';
$tag='tag';
$model='model';
$upc='upc';
$ean='ean';
$jan='jan';
$isbn='isbn';
$mpn='mpn';
$location='location';
$image='image';
$stock='stock_status';
$category ='categories';
$options = 'options' ;

foreach ($stores['data'][$Products] as $review) {
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
    $product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product");

    try {
        $product
            ->setStoreId(0)
            ->setAttributeSetId(4)
            ->setTypeId('simple')
            ->setSku($review[$sku])
            ->setName($review[$name])
            ->setWeight($review[$weight])
            ->setStatus($review[$status])
            ->setTaxClassId($review[$tax])
            ->setVisibility(4)
            ->setPrice($review[$rate])
            ->setMetaTitle($review[$meta_title])
            ->setMetaKeyword($review[$meta_keyword])
            ->setMetaDescription($review[$meta_description])
            ->setDescription($review[$description])
            ->setShortDescription($review[$description])
            ->setStockData(array(
                    'qty' => $review[$quantity]
                )
            )
            ->setCategoryIds(array($review[$category]));

        foreach ($review['options'] as $pro_opt) {
            foreach ($pro_opt['product_option_value'] as $pro) {
                $product
                    ->setProductOptions($pro[$options])
                    ->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
                $product->save();
                echo $pro['product_option_value_id'] . "<br>";
                echo $pro['option_value_id'] . "<br>";
                echo $pro['name'] . "<br>";
                echo $pro['image'] . "<br>";
                echo $pro['quantity'] . "<br>";
                echo $pro['subtract'] . "<br>";
                echo $pro['price'] . "<br>";
                echo $pro['price_prefix'] . "<br>";
                echo $pro['weight'] . "<br>";
                echo $pro['weight_prefix'] . "<br>";
            }
        }

        $product->save();
        $err = curl_error($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
    }

}
```

CUSTOM OPTIONS JSON FORMAT:

```
"options": [{
    "product_option_id": "1474614118575",
    "product_option_value": [{
        "product_option_value_id": "14746141182837",
        "option_value_id": "14746141181",
        "name": "XS",
        "image": "",
        "quantity": "2",
        "subtract": "1",
        "price": "0.0000",
        "price_prefix": "+",
        "weight": "0.00000000",
        "weight_prefix": "+"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use below code,

```
foreach ($review['options'] as $pro_opt) {
    $optionInstance = $product->getOptionInstance()->unsetOptions();
    $options = Mage::helper('core')->jsonDecode($pro_opt['product_option_value']);
    $product->setHasOptions(1);
    $optionInstance->addOption($options);
    $optionInstance->setProduct($product);
    $product->save();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
/**
 * Include Mage.php of your Magento installation
 */
require_once("../magento/app/Mage.php");
umask(0);

/**
 * Initialize Magento
 */
Mage::app('default');

// In the following example code, I am adding custom option with title ‘Size’
// and I have added two values to it ‘Long’ and ‘Short’.

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$productId = 905;
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

$options = array(
    'title' => 'Size',
    'type' => 'drop_down',
    'is_required' => 1,
    'sort_order' => 0,
    'values' => array(
        array(
            'title' => 'Long',
            'price' => 10.50,
            'price_type' => 'fixed',
            'sku' => '',
            'sort_order' => 0,
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Short',
            'price' => 0,
            'price_type' => 'percent',
            'sku' => 'test-product-sku',
            'sort_order' => 0,
        )
    )
);

$product->setProductOptions(array($options));
$product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
$product->save();
```

You can now see the following custom options when you edit your product in admin:
[image]

Comment: What if you want to add the options to multiple products?